# Which of the LEGO Mindstorms 9797 (NXT Education base set) Software is compatible with Windows 10

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, software

I have LEGO Mindstorms NXT 9797 and downloaded the following Windows PC Versions:

- NXT Edu 2.1F6 PC App ---Education Version
- NXT Ret 2.0F5 PC App ---Home Version

Which one of these are compatible with Windows 10 home version 64bit?

Is EV3 software a better choice for this one?

Your guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: No answers? Really? Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck; All versions of the NXT software, including drivers, is compatible with 64-bit Windows 10. While in my experience it wasn't necessary, you can preemptively avoid installation problems by right-clicking "Setup.exe" and clicking Properties -> Compatibility -> Run in compatibility mode for: -> Windows XP SP3 . In the same panel you should select "Run as Administrator" to avoid permission problems.

While the EV3 software is backward-compatible with the NXT, the NXT software is a much better option. Certain NXT options are not available using the EV3 software (like bluetooth support). And in my experience, the NXT software is just more stable anyway.